# Copied Weight Painted Arm Disappears After Joining Back to Main Armature

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

so here's my issue.
Essentially, to avoid weight painting the same limb twice, I've made an attempt to just copy the arm I've already weight painted, mirrored it, & then renamed all the bones. However, when I attempt to attach the new arm's armature to the main armature with ctrl+J, the new arm's mesh disappears.

I'm not sure what exactly is causing this because every previous person who's asked a similar question doesn't appear to have this issue? Is it an order thing? Do I need to join the arm mesh to the main mesh first?

[ File is a bit too big for the normal site, so here's a g.drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N14OdMEOujBU85978oUM6cAhWAmJN-lG/view?usp=sharing ]

Additionally, since I will be attaching the file after posting, my model's eyes are parented to the head but do not move with the head bone. If someone knows where I missed a connection there, please also mention that in your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cause of the disappear of the left arm.**
When joined, the left arm overlaps the right arm.
This is because the Arm Armature's scale(x=-1) was canceled by join.

**The reason why the eyes do not move with the head bone.**

This is because the eyes are parented to the head mesh object, not bone.

**wrong name of the left arm**
l.u.arm.001

[image]

**Remake**

Actually, it seems to me far more easy and more profitable to recreate the mesh and bones than to fix bugs. The following way uses ***mirror modifier*** and ***symmetry method*** to create the necessary parts.

1. Delete Arm Armature and Arms.002
2. In object mode, set objects origin to world origin:
   (1) Shift+S with Cursor to World Origin,
   (2) Select Main Armature and Arms.001 mesh objects,
   (3) Menu: Object > Set Origin > Orign to 3D Cursor.
3. Make left arm mesh by Mirror modifier:
   (1) Add Mirror modifier to Arms.001 and Apply the modifier.
4. Make left arm bones by Symmetrize method.
   (1) In edit mode, select all arm bones of the Arm Armature,
   (2) Menu: Armature menu > Symmetrize.

[image]